# Round bracket () placement in javascript - unusual syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I've come across the following code  [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/) :

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();
```

Now i'm fairly new to javascript and I have some questions about the syntax. First of all the MDN defines the requestAnimationFrame method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.requestAnimationFrame), yet in this example they are calling it without the () on the end, secondly there seems to be an extra () right before the final semicolon. I don't really understand the reasoning in both cases, so some enlightenment would be really helpful!

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's an [`IIFE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) In your example it tests which method exists (if none then the final function) and assigns it to `window.requestAnimFrame` It's better practice to have the final `()` inside the closng bracket `(function(){
  /* code */ 
}());`

Comment: Where do you see them calling it without the `()` on the end? Post whatever you're referring to in your question.

Comment: Cookie Monster: On line 2, the method is called as requestAnimationFrame instead of requestAnimationFrame(), I don't really understand why.

Comment: The method isn't called. It is the return value of the outer function.

Comment: `()` is called parenthesis, not round brackets

Comment: cheers Markasoftware, parenthesis it is.

Comment: @Markasoftware It's a perfectly common and accepted term. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brackets#Types_and_uses In programming, we frequently have "square", "round", "curly", and "pointy" brackets, meaning different things in different places; giving them all different names doesn't really help (and reserving "brackets" for `[` and `]` would be particularly foolish).

Comment: @Markasoftware Oh, and `(` is a parenthesis, `()` are a pair of parentheses, plural. If you're going to be pedantic, best get it right :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are no brackets next to the inner function names because they are not being *called* (executed), they are simply being *referenced*. Basically, the function is checking to see which function exists, and `return`ing a reference to the first one it finds. In this way, you end up with a reference to the available version of the function on all browsers.
2. The extra brackets at the end *are* executing a function - the anonymous function which starts `(function(callback) {` and ends `})`. This is known as an ["IIFE"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and is a way of grouping code together in JS, with its own variable scope, but immediately calculating the answer.

The net result is that `window.requestAnimFrame` ends up pointing to whichever of the functions exists, or the dummy implementation `window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60)`.

That function hasn't actually been called, but code can now call `window.requestAnimFrame(something)` without fear of it not existing.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is called an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (abbreviated IIFE).  You can read a lot more about them [here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

In a nutshell, it's a function definition that immediately executes and the return value from the immediate execution is assigned to `window.requestAnimFrame`.  This is just setting the function that will be in `window.requestAnimFrame`.  There are no parens after `window.requestAnimFrame` here because this code isn't executing that particular function.  It's executing some other function (thus why there are parens at the end) and assigning the result of that function to `window.requestAnimFrame` so that when that is called sometime in the future, it will call the appropriate function.

The IIFE can be explained as follows...

You know this syntax as a function definition:

```
function() {
}
```

That is then wrapped in an additional set of parens to make it so the JS interpreter treats it as an expression to evaluate like this:

```
(function() {
})
```

Then, to make it execution that function expression, the `()` is added at the end to have this:

```
(function() {
})();
```

Then, inside the code of that function that is executed is a `return` statement which causes the result of that immediately executed function to be returned and that return value is assigned to `window.requestAnimFrame`.  In simplified form, this is:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return x;
})();
```

Where `x` turns out to be a function itself that is the result of some other calculations.  The main advantages to using an IIFE in this instance are to pre-evaluate some code that is just run once so `window.requestAnimFrame` will run faster whenever it's called.

The most common use of an IIFE is to create a function scope to isolate variables from the parent or global scope without having to create a named function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly interesting nesting of function calls, actually.  Let's start in the "inner-most" function.  Look at what it's doing:

```
function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
};
```

It's a function definition which accepts another function as a parameter.  It then calls that function with a timeout.  Understanding that functions themselves are objects in JavaScript, this definition of a function is itself an object, which leads us to the next level outward:

```
return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
       window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
       window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
       window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
       window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
       function(callback) {
           window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
       };
```

This code is returning a function object.  Either one that's already defined on the `window` object (the first one it finds, really) or, if nothing else, the one it defines at the end.  Again, functions being objects which can be passed around like variables, this is just returning a value from a function.  That value itself happens to be a function, which can be executed at a later time.

This whole structure is wrapped in a function of its own:

```
function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
           window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
           function(callback) {
               window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
           };
}
```

So *this* function returns a function.  We then wrap the whole thing in parentheses and execute it:

```
(function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
           window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
           function(callback) {
               window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
           };
})()
```

So now that function which returns a function then gets executed with the `()` after it.  So the value of this whole thing is, well, a function.  Specifically, this evaluates to the function returned by the inner function.  That function then, as a value, is assigned to a variable:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
           window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
           function(callback) {
               window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
           };
})();
```

So, overall what this whole thing does is assign a function to `window.requestAnimFrame`.  It does so through some interesting nesting of functions, but ultimately that's all it's doing.